# Changing UINavigationController Back Button Image Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I am trying to change the navigation controller back button, but am facing problems with the image not being inline. I have removed the text by clicking on the navigation Item in the view controllers and changing the back button text to a single space " ".

[image]

Then I change the navigation bar back image to my custom one in the Navigation Controller scene.

[image]

But the image is not inline.

[image]

Does anybody know why this is or what are the best practises to change the back button image.

Answer (score 0):

Id suggest you take a look at your image and make sure the back arrow is correctly positioned in the image. That may be what is causing it look like it is push upwards.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:(float)0.0 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Which would change the vertical positioning of your title to match the image. However, it may the make your `rightBarButtonItem` to look out of place.